# How to do case-sensitive find & replace in Excel file with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, replace, html-entities

I want to use Powershell to find special characters (like Greek letters) in an Excel document and replace them with HTML entities. My script looks like this:

```
$file = "C:\Path\To\File\test.xls"
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $True
$objWorkbook = $xl.Workbooks.Open($file)
$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$objRange = $objWorksheet.UsedRange

$charArray = @(
([char]948, "&delta;"),
([char]916, "&Delta;")
)

foreach ($char in $charArray){
    $FindText = $char[0]
    $ReplaceText = $char[1]
    if ($objRange.find("$FindText")) {
        $objRange.replace("$FindText", $ReplaceText)
    } else {write-host "Didn't find $FindText"}
}
```

The trouble is, the `.find()` and `.replace()` methods are not case-sensitive, so `[char]948` (δ) matches both the lowercase delta (δ) and uppercase delta (Δ) characters. The result is that all δ and Δ characters in the Excel (.xls) file are replaced with `&delta;`.

In VBA, Range.Find() has a MatchCase parameter, but it does not seem that Powershell allows it. For example, `$objRange.find("$FindText", MatchCase:=$True)` does not work.

I also tried Powershell's `-cmatch` and `-creplace` commands, which are case-sensitive, but I could not figure out how to get those to work on the Excel range object `$objRange`:

`$objRange -creplace "$FindText", $ReplaceText` has no effect on the Excel file.

I can't export or convert the data to .txt or .csv because the special characters don't survive the conversion.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: There is a match case parameter in the range.Find excel's method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: @David Brabant: But can the Range.Find method's parameters be used from Powershell? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Using PowerShell you can use creplace operator

```
"aAaAaA" -creplace 'a','I'
IAIAIA
```

To replace find you can use the IndexOf method from the `string` class it takes a `comparisonType`

```
IndexOf(string value, int startIndex, int count, System.StringComparison comparisonType)
```

Example :

```
"Jean Paul".indexOF("paul", 0, [System.StringComparison]::CurrentCulture)
-1
"Jean Paul".indexOF("paul", 0, [System.StringComparison]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
5
```

Comment: But do these methods find/replace in an Excel file? If so, how? I tried -creplace, but it has no effect in Excel.